# NSLogger Viewer

Tags: xcode, swift3

is NSLogger Viewer working for anyone? I'm running Xcode8b6 and can't get any of the sample files to actually log something into the app. 
I even rebuild NSLoggerViewer from scratch and when running it in the debug mode, it reports following issue:

```
2016-08-28 21:13:51.208393 NSLogger[32974:1208999] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2016-08-28 21:13:51.208580 NSLogger[32974:1208999] Stream error occurred: stream=<__NSCFInputStream: 0x6180001046e0> self=<LoggerNativeTransport 0x600000083390 listenerPort=63262 publishBonjourService=1 secure=1> error=Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-9806 " : t" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=4294957490, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2016-08-28 21:14:48.142366 NSLogger[32974:1208999] incoming connection
2016-08-28 21:14:48.143200 NSLogger[32974:1208999] setupSSLForStream, stream=<__NSCFInputStream: 0x610000104ec0> self=<LoggerNativeTransport 0x600000083390 listenerPort=63262 publishBonjourService=1 secure=1> serverCerts=(
    "<SecIdentity 0x608000269440 [0x7fffe148cbd0]>",
    "<cert(0x1005884d0) s: NSLogger self-signed SSL i: NSLogger self-signed SSL>"
)
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: working ok for me, but I am using Xcode 7...

Comment: I use pre-built one, no problem at all. If you just want to view log why bother build that yourself ?

Comment: Could you post a link to built version?